# Globally disable a default warning

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Since the last update, GHCi is showing lots of `Warning: Tab character` messages and I want to set this warning message to be disabled by default.

Is there a config file I can create/edit to set the `-fnowarn-tabs` flag globally?

Comment: I think I might have found a config file for GHCi I could create, from https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html .. Checking it out now. It doesn't seem to change the defaults of GHC however.

Comment: You should rather want to `sed` all those tab characters out of your documents, methinks.

Comment: Replacing the tabs with spaces is an option, but that's not what I'm after right now.

Comment: leftroundabout: what is the recommended way to `sed` this out?

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 I'd simply go with `sed 's/\t/ ⁸/g' -i`, unless this doesn't work. (That's supposed to be _eight space characters_; StackOverflow doesn't let me use them in a code snippet. Of course, if your code is trimmed for 4-space tab width, use four spaces!) As this can go wrong in a number of ways; first try `sed 's/\t/ ⁸/g' | view +'setf haskell' -` to see what happens.

Comment: @leftaroundabout it's not what my editor thinks about tabs, but what Haskell standard thinks, no? I know how to replace one char (tab) by a string (spaces) - I was hoping to learn about an sed trick that gets tab sematics right. Perhaps it's not needed (if lines start with all tabs).

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 Haskell standard is one tab means align to the next 8-spaces column. So you are right that simply replacing all tabs with 8 spaces will **not** work in general; you'd need to add as much spaces until the column is a multiple of 8 for each tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For GHCi, a config file can be added to your AppData or home directory, as per [GHC documentation: The .ghci file](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html). For Windows this file is %APPDATA%\ghc\ghci.conf.

You can add the following line, as described by [the warnings page](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0-latest/docs/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html), to disable the Tab warning in GHCi:

```
:set -fno-warn-tabs
```